# Finding XML nodes in which an attribute's value contains a specific character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have an XML file (many MB in size), which I view using Notepad++. Many of the XML nodes are of the form:

```
<ItemInfo ID="something" Name="some name1" />
```

The ID attribute can have values containing special characters like semicolon (;).

Example:

```
<ItemInfo ID="something" Name="some name1" />
<ItemInfo ID="some;thing;" Name="some name2" />
<ItemInfo ID="some;thing" Name="some name3" />
```

Now, I want to go over all occurrences (using regex in the Find feature) in which the value of the ID attribute contains one or more semicolons (;).

After seeing some example on the web, I tried the following with no success.

`"<ItemInfo ID="".*";`

`"<ItemInfo ID=""(.*)";`

`"<ItemInfo ID=\"".*";""\""`

In essence, I'd like to find all strings:

containing a specific character,

starting with some fixed text, and

ending with some fixed text.

Can anyone please give a solution or point me in the right direction? I think I'd have to do the same kind of operation frequently in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to find all strings which contain a `;` in the `ID`:

```
<ItemInfo ID="[^"]*;[^"]*
```

To find strings having an `ID` that starts with some fixed text:

```
<ItemInfo ID="text[^"]*"
```

And to find strings having an `ID` that end with some fixed text:

```
<ItemInfo ID="[^"]*text"
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
.*ID=.*[;].*Name=.*
```

More info on how notepad++ does regex is [here](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)